# "that exposure" or "the exposure"

Tags: articles

> I belive that your company will give me ***that*** exposure I need to contribute my skills.

OR

> I belive that your company will give me ***the*** exposure I need to contribute my skills.

Which one is correct?

Comment: What do dictionaries say about the determiner usage of 'that'?

Comment: Requests for writing help are off topic because they do not help anyone but the asker. The only exception is when there is a clearly identified source of concern about an element of the English language which would be interesting and useful to many future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your company will give me **the** exposure I need to contribute my skills.

"that" would only be used if you're referring to something highly specific/singular, which in your example it's more generic and plural.

Here's an example where you might use **that** instead.

"let's try and get exposure from facebook marketing." "Yes, we definitely need **that** exposure"

This is referring to a specific area of exposure, so it's more of a singular entity, so you could say that. That being said, you could also use **the** here, it would just mean something very very slightly different. Saying **the** would more mean they need exposure in general, while **that** would target the specific item.

Let me know if any of this is confusing or needs clarification.

Also, your sentence is a little strange sounding, this sounds like it's for a resume, so I'll clean that up for you:

"I believe that your company will give me the perfect environment and atmosphere to contribute my skills."

exposure in the context you used it sounds like personal exposure in terms of job opportunities, which is not what companies want to hear.

Comment: Can you please add support for your answer? Without support, others may see it as merely an opinion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Actually, the sentence is for cover letter. I'm going to replace the word "exposure" or I will use a different phrasing...

Answer (score 0):

I believe both are technically correct, but using **that** sounds weird because when we hear `that [noun] [independent clause]` we automatically want to think of **that** as the object and the independent clause modifying it with **which**. For example:

> I believe that your company will give me that exposure **which** I need to contribute my skills.

It's the difference between **exposure I need** being the object of **give me** and **that** being the object. Our brains want to hear **that** as the object whereas grammatically **exposure I need** is the object and **that** is a definite article.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Your explanation makes sense to me.

Comment: @NextJordan glad to help! I'd appreciate the upvote/accept!